# Calculator with Javascript and 2 fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am supposed to make a calculator (it's supposed to be done by tomorrow) and it's in Javascript and I am taking this distance course and they've just introduced Javascript with this assignment and I don't understand any of the code and what it means. I understand HTML and CSS but JS is just something I don't understand at all.

I have gotten started on the code but I cannot get any further because I can't find anything online of a calculator like this or any easy explanation of JS. It is supposed to not have a submit-button and the design is irrelevant but it's supposed to have two text fields.

```js
function Calculate() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  number1_parsed = parseInt(tal1);
  tal2_parsed = parseInt(tal2);
  if (number1_parsed) {} else
    alert("Wrong characters");
  return false;
} {
  summa = number1_parsed + number2_parsed;
  alert("Sum" + sum);
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <h1> Calculator </h1>
  <form name="kalkylator">
    <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" size="10" />
    <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" size="10" />
    <input type="button" onclick="Calculate();" id="calculate" value="Result">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe just pay attention in class?

Comment: how about learn js? Like isn't that why you go to the class?

Comment: What is your actual question? What is working? What isn't? What errors are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your code clearly formatted. It helps simplify debugging. Keep your indentation accurate. Had you done this you would probably have seen the messed up curly braces.

Also you were inconsistent in your variable names.

For example:

- You have no open curly brace (`{`) after your `else`
- You have a random open curly brace before this line: `summa = number1_parsed + number2_parsed;`
- You call `parseInt(tal1);` but your variable is `number1` and not `tal1`
- You use `summa` to hold the sum, but your `alert` uses `sum`

```js
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");

function Calculate() {
  var number1_parsed = parseInt(number1.value);
  var number2_parsed = parseInt(number2.value);
  if (isNaN(number1_parsed) || isNaN(number2_parsed)) {
    alert("Wrong characters");
    return false;
  }

  var sum = number1_parsed + number2_parsed;
  alert("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <h1> Calculator </h1>
  <form name="kalkylator">
    <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" size="10" />
    <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" size="10" />
    <input type="button" onclick="Calculate();" id="calculate" value="Result">
  </form>
</div>
```